# why two instances of logger used in this java class?

Tags: java, logging

In java code I saw two instances of logger like this,

```
private static final Logger error = LoggerFactory.getLogger("log.error");
private static final Logger warn = LoggerFactory.getLogger("log.warn");
```

warn instance calling warn method,

```
warn.warn()
```

and error instance calls,

```
error.error()
error.isErrorEnabled()
```

What is use of using two instances?
why not use single instance?

Comment: My guess would be because of some difference of the underlying behavior that cannot be achieved by a single instance. E.g. writing to different output sources (files, mailers, log concentrators, whatever). Difficult to say without more context

Comment: @lab419 All of those can be achieved with a single instance unless you're using some home grown logging framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original author of the code may have wanted to direct warnings and errors to their own files (or other destinations), but didn't understand how to do it via configuration.

Normally you only need a single logger, which you can then configure to perform different things depending on whether you're using `warn()` or `error()`.

There's no good reason to use multiple loggers in a single class.